# How to convert (M d, D) to (Y-m-d) in PHP?

Tags: php

How to convert `M d, D` = `Jan 17, Tue` to `Y-m-d` = `2017-01-17` in PHP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
echo date('Y-m-d',strtotime('Jan 17, Tue'));
```

Answer (score 3):

```
echo date('Y-m-d',strtotime('Jan 17, Tue'));
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', "17/01/2017");
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

Source - http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php

Hope this helps...